# Read and Write to Google Sheets using JSON backend

Tags: json, google-sheets-api

I am trying to accomplish the same as the GitHub link, anyone has experience and can suggest a successful best practice?

[Google Apps Script to read JSON and write to sheet](https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1442370)

Comment: Found it, for Python [link](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app) from a previous stackoverflow article: Reading & Writing JSON file on Google Cloud Storage using Python

Answer (score 0):

Found it, for Python [Python Bookshelf App](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app) from a previous stackoverflow article: Reading & Writing JSON file on Google Cloud Storage using Python, I believe there is the same for Java, have to review a bit more [Java on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/java/)